# Using BeautifulSoup to find h3 when only given substring of its title

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml

I am trying to gather data from a Jeopardy website. In particular, I want to gather the dollar amounts from the table of data from this [site](http://www.j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=6432):

[image]

It is displayed like so in lxml:

[image]

I can do this with the following line of code:

`scores = [int(score.text.replace('$','').replace(',','')) for score in soupEpisode.find('h3', string='Scores at the first commercial break (after clue 15)').findNext('table').find_all('tr')[1].find_all('td')]`

However, there are times where the table is displayed slightly differently (with "16" instead of "15"), like so:

[image]

As a result, the part of my code that does

`soupEpisode.find('h3', string='Scores at the first commercial break (after clue 15)')`

will return "None". Is there a way to do the find method with only a substring of the h3 name? If I could write the same line of code with just needing the "Scores at the first commercial break" substring, I believe it would work for all cases. Thanks!

Edit:

To test, download the html version of [this site](http://www.j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=6431) and the following code snippet should work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def main(): 
    #episode_file should be "8062.html"
    episode = open(episode_file, encoding="utf-8")
    soupEpisode = BeautifulSoup(episode, 'lxml')
    episode.close()

    first_commercial_break = [int(score.text.replace('$','').replace(',','')) for score in soupEpisode.find('h3', string=string='Scores at the first commercial break (after clue 15)').findNext('table').find_all('tr')[1].find_all('td')]

    return first_commercial_break
```

Comment: Do you want the h3 text or table (Laurel, $1,000, etc...)?

Comment: The "scores = ..." line will return a list [2800, 0, 7200]. So I first want to find the correct table, then get the dollar amounts in it

Comment: Using regex with the re module would do the job

Comment: Could you post or show me the full code so I could do some testing?

Comment: I'm thinking that `soupEpisode.find('h3', string=re.compile("Scores at the first commercial break (after clue .*)")` should work

Comment: @pythonier500 I tried your code and it didn't work. I posted a code snippet that should allow for testing!

Comment: @Anthony Alright thank you I will try a few things and let you know what works!

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: There has to be a better way of identifying the element, no? Can you share some of the surrounding HTML? As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Sorry about the screenshot! I have linked the site where the HTML screenshot comes from, but the specific element and surrounding HTML can be found on line 663 of the page source from here: view-source:http://www.j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=6431

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code. It finds h3 including 'Scores at the first commercial break' and then find the table below the h3.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
html_content = urlopen('http://www.j-archive.com/showgame.php?game_id=6432')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "lxml")
for h3 in soup.find_all('h3'):
    if 'Scores at the first commercial break' in h3.text:
        new_html_content = str(soup).split(str(h3))[1]

soup = BeautifulSoup(new_html_content, "lxml")
name_list = [td.text for td in soup.find('table').find('tr').find_all('td')]
dollar_list = [td.text for td in soup.find('table').find_all('tr')[1].find_all('td')]

print(name_list)
print(dollar_list)
```

Print result is as follows.

```
['Kevin', 'Julie', 'Bill']
['$2,800', '$0', '$7,200']
```

Comment: This will work, I downloaded the page and changed the values of the round number and it still produced the correct output.